# Angular 7: Erro ao tentar instalar o PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primefaces

**Ao executar o comando de instalação acontece o seguinte erro:**

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Alisson:nutriclinweb-ui alissonfernando$ npm install 
primeng --save
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near 
'...:"primeng","version":'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alissonfernando/.npm/_logs/2019-05- 
02T18_54_35_157Z-debug.log
```

**Log completo do erro:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'primeng',
1 verbose cli   '--save' ]
2 info using npm@6.8.0
3 info using node@v10.14.2
4 verbose npm-session b73d47248850dfc7
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/primeng 3679ms (from         cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for primeng@latest Unexpected end of     JSON input while parsing near '...:"primeng","version":'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 8598ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while     parsing near '...:"primeng","version":'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson     (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50)
11 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
12 verbose cwd /Users/alissonfernando/Documents/4o ANO/ESTAG. SUP./Projeto/nutriclinweb/Codificação/Interface/nutriclinweb-ui
13 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
14 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "primeng" "--save"
15 verbose node v10.14.2
16 verbose npm  v6.8.0
17 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"primeng","version":'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: talvez seu package.json esteja mal formatado, faltando uma virgula ou algo assim.

Comment: o package.json está normal...

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema excluindo totalmente o Node e reinstalando o mesmo, como sugere o tópico a seguir: [Como excluir completamente o Node e reinstalar em todos os sistemas.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)